# C#: How do I get a nested data from table?

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core

I'm newbie in C# and I faced a next tricky problem:

There are three JSON files for seeding three data tables. To keep it simple for understanding I will refer to my data as cars with the tables `Manufacturers`, `CarType`, `CarModel`.

So, let's assume there are 3 tables:

**1st** is the Main Table (*CarModel*). There are columns like: `Id, Name, MaxSpeed, ... id_of_manufacturer, id_of_car_type`

```
Example of data:
['1', 'E34', '250', ... , '1', '1'] //BMW -> Sedan
['2', 'X6', '220', ... , '1', '2']  //BMW -> SUV
['3', 'Q7', '240', ... , '2', '2']  //Audi -> SUV
```

**2nd** Table *CarType* with the mostly constant rows and next columns: `Id, Type, ...`

```
Example of data
[1, "Sedan", ...]
[2, "SUV", ...]
```

**3rd** Table *Manufacturers* with the mostly constant rows and next columns: `Id, Company, ...`

```
Example of data
[1, "BMW", ...]
[2, "AUDI", ...]
```

So the relations between tables are like this:
There is a CarModel, "E34", that in the same table reffers to CarType (id_of_car_type) "Sedan" and Manufacturer (id_of_manufacturer) "BMW".

My Question is, how to make a request to the database, so the response will have all data from CarModel table and data in it will look like this?

```
1, BMW, ...
    1, Sedan, ...
        1, E34, 250, ...
    2, SUV, ...
        2, X6, 220, ...
2, Audi, ...
    2, SUV, ...
        3, Q7, 240, ...
```

Comment: Have you referred the SQL documentation to get results as JSON, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Please see this post about homework. [How do I ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) Please include the code you have so far.

Comment: @JohnV Honestly, it sounds more like an interview assignment than a school homework. Whichever the case, this is too broad. Mortrus, you need to read [ask].

Comment: @Mortrus I think the problem is it's not entirely clear what you're asking us to do. Do you have three JSON strings and want to turn them into a C# object (or another JSON string?) of the format shown?  If so that's not really a 'request to the database'.  If you do mean a request to the database, then are you asking for SQL to join three tables and return JSON?  If so this isn't really a C#/asp.net question.

Comment: @RichN, that three JSON strings seed the tables. In general I need an ICollection of three joined tables by some request, which I'm looking for... I tried to get all I want by for loops. It's working, but seems for me as ineffective solution.

Comment: Hi, what is your requirement? It seems to be not clear. What do you mean for `how to make a request`? What operation do you want to do with database? Add Main record with related table data to database or any other operation? What have you done now? Could you pls share enough code?

Comment: @Rena, I've shared my code in new answer...

Answer (score 0):

Currently my solution is like this, but I think that it has a performance issues at least...

```
namespace Cars.Data;

public class CarsRepository : ICarsRepository {
    private readonly DataContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public CarsRepository(DataContext context, IMapper mapper) {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<CarTypes>> GetCarTypesForManufacturer(int id)
    {
        var carTypes = await _context.CarModels
            .Where(r => r.ManufacturerId == id)
            .Select(s => new {s.CarTypeId})
            .Distinct()
            .Select(s => s.CarTypeId)
            .ToListAsync();
        
        return await _context.CarTypes.Where(p => carTypes.Contains(p.Id)).ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<Cars>> GetAllCars() {
        ICollection<Cars> result = new Collection<Cars>();
        var manufacturers = await _context.CarManufacturers.ToListAsync();
        foreach (var manufacturer in manufacturers) {
            var carTypes = await GetCarTypesForManufacturer(manufacturer.Id);
            ICollection<CarTypesWithCarModels> temp = new Collection<CarTypesWithCarModels>();
            foreach (var carType in carTypes) {
                var carModels = await _context.CarModels
                    .Where(r => r.ManufacturerId == manufacturer.Id && r.CarTypeId == carType.Id)
                    .ToListAsync();

                temp.Add(new CarTypesWithCarModels {
                    Id = carType.Id,
                    Name = carType.Name,
                    CarModels = carModels
                });
            }
            result.Add(new Cars {
                Id = manufacturer.Id,
                Name = manufacturer.Name,
                CarTypes = temp
            });
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```